# Как реализован механизм, который определяет количество "воды" в тексте?

Tags: алгоритм, работа-с-текстом

На сайте [text.ru](https://text.ru/antiplagiat/unauthorized), есть инструмент определяющий уникальность текста, орфографию, количество воды и заспамленность. Какой алгоритм работы последних двух опций?

Comment: Я не знаю, что конкретно там сделано, но я кое-что понимаю в этом деле. Какую задачу Вы хотите решить?

Comment: @Александр Муксимов, интересует, как машина может определять такие данные, откуда берет и каким образом, это личный интерес

Comment: Это один из возможных подходов https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_essay_scoring#Criticism

Answer (score 3):

В указанном вами источнике указано по поводу "воды":

> Данный параметр отображает процент наличия в тексте стоп-слов, фразеологизмов, а также словесных оборотов, фраз, соединительных слов, являющихся не значимыми и не несущими смысловой нагрузки.

То есть собран некий словарь "не значащих и не несущих смысловой нагрузки" (По мнению авторов. Лично я без этих слов смысл текста теряю) слов и выражений. Выделить/сопоставить в обрабатываемом тексте слова по данному словарю и назвать их "водой" - "дело техники".

По поводу "заспамленности".

> Процент заспамленности текста отражает количество поисковых ключевых слов в тексте.
>           Чем больше в тексте ключевых слов, тем выше его заспамленность:

Тоже словарь неких поисковых слов. Выделяем, сопоставляем, называем как хотим.

Исскуственного интеллекта и семантических сетей, я лично, там не предполагаю.